# How can Add items to Binded Datasource Combo Box?

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, combobox, datasource

Hi I am new to C#. I have tried following way to add new item to my bound ComboBox but it won't give any result.
Is it possible to add new item to bound ComboBox (Here Problem is `ID` is `Bigint` data type but I want to add `Select ID`)?
If it  is possible, please provide piece of code

```
     try
        {
            objSqlExecute.OpenConnection();
            string strQuery = objQueryManager.GetEmployeeRecords();
                  //Add Extra Items to combo Box
            cmbEmployeeID.Items.Add("Select Id");

            DataTable dtEmployee = objSqlExecute.GetRecordExecution(strQuery);
                 // DataRow dtNew = dtEmployee.NewRow();
                // dtNew["ID"] = "Select ID";
                // dtNew["FName"] = "";
            //dtEmployee.Rows.InsertAt(dtNew, 0);

            cmbEmployeeID.DataSource = dtEmployee;
            cmbEmployeeID.DisplayMember = "ID";
            cmbEmployeeID.ValueMember = "FName";
        }
```

Comment: Try to add the item after setting the data source

Comment: it is showing `Items collection cannot be modified when the DataSource property is set` this exception @Amiram Korach

Comment: What happened when you added it to the table?

Comment: if i Remove comment on these lines     `DataRow dtNew = dtEmployee.NewRow();
                dtNew["ID"] = "Select ID";
                dtNew["FName"] = "";
               dtEmployee.Rows.InsertAt(dtNew, 0);`                 
       It was giving error like

`Input string was not in a correct format.Couldn't store <Select ID> in ID Column.  Expected type is Byte`.   i Know because this column is `bigint` datatype

Comment: Why are you displaying the ID? It is more common to show the name and use the ID as value.

Comment: I already had changed as you said .. thank you

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19213/discussion-between-rangasathish-and-amiram-korach)

Answer (score 0):

```
try
    {
        objSqlExecute.OpenConnection();
        string strQuery = objQueryManager.GetEmployeeRecords();
              //Add Extra Items to combo Box            

        DataTable dtEmployee = objSqlExecute.GetRecordExecution(strQuery);                 

        cmbEmployeeID.DataSource = dtEmployee;
        cmbEmployeeID.DisplayMember = "ID";
        cmbEmployeeID.ValueMember = "FName";

        cmbEmployeeID.Items.Insert(0, "None Selected");
    }
```

Comment: from where should i get `ListItem` Method? it will give error like doesn't have any method

Answer (score 0):

1. Did you try your query to make sure it returns values? returning multiple records, single or none?
2. Do you want to add ONE new item at random intervals? 
   Or else do you have an option to INSERT all items at once?

Can you try adding `toString()` for converting `BigInt`?

Notes:
The [arcticle here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2496/How-to-set-values-into-ComboBox-Items) gives an insight to add a new item to a combobox using sql.
Looking at the questions you are posting, to see a sample of how to use **ListItems** in this scenario, you could refer to the [web link.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15857/Add-Item-to-Binded-Combo-Box)